# Determining how many nodes are allocated to a user in qsub system

Tags: hpc, qsub

Is there a way to see how many nodes are allocated to a user (me) in the qsub system?

Also how can one see how many nodes/cores a process is using in effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get info about user by calling

```
qstat -u user_name
```

it shows the nodes in one of the columns.

If you want to get very detailed info regarding job, you can always call:

```
qstat -f job_id
```

And you should get info regarding all the details related to given job.

Comment: Thanks although for the second question I mean how many cores are being used at the moment (something similar to the top command).